# The operation of retrieving checkbox elements with a specific CLASS NAME using jQuery has failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to set only one of the following two checkboxes to be selected at a time.
`jQuery` only captures the elements of the parent layer (`staffTypeSet`), but cannot capture those of the child layer(`.staffType2`).

Image:

[image]

code:

```js
$('.staffType2').click(function () {
 $(".staffType2").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

The JavaScript code I designed had no effect at all. What could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Seems odd to use JS for this when the native radio control has this behaviour by default.

Comment: Yes, but my client insists on using checkboxes instead of radio buttons.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works just fine - add some debugging to your code to see what's happening (I would guess that your checkboxes are created dynamically, after that code you posted is run)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I've attempted to insert console.log() into the code, but I noticed that the output didn't appear. This suggests that jQuery was unable to identify elements with the class "staffType2". However, when I changed the jQuery selector to target the parent element (staffTypeSet), it was able to identify the elements. Additionally, the checkboxes are indeed dynamically generated and their classes are generated based on the quantity of data.

Comment: I have found the reason and solution. $(selector).click(fn) triggers the callback function fn when the selected selector is clicked. It only works for selectors that already exist on the page.
The $(document).on method includes many events such as click, double-click, and so on. It can be used similarly to $().click(), but the main advantage is that if dynamically created elements are within the selected scope, they can trigger the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to uncheck a checkbox is to use the `.prop()` method instead of `.removeAttr()`.

Here's the corrected sample code:

```js
$('.staffType2').click(function () {
  $(".staffType2").not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="staffType2" type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input class="staffType2" type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input class="staffType2" type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label>
```

However, if you want to allow only one checkbox to be selected at a time, I recommend using radio buttons instead. Radio buttons are designed for this purpose, and you won't need any additional jQuery code to achieve the desired behavior.

To use radio buttons, change the input type to radio and give them the same name attribute. For example:

```html
<input id="vehicle1" type="radio" class="staffType2" name="staffType" value="1">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
<input id="vehicle2" type="radio" class="staffType2" name="staffType" value="2">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
```

With radio buttons, only one can be selected at a time within the group with the same name attribute.

Comment: original code works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Becase prop and attribute are different.

Use `prop` instead of `removeAttr`

Like this example from your question

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
check boxes
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="staffType" class="staffType2">醫事人員</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="staffType2" class="staffType2">醫生</input>
</div>

<script>
$('.staffType2').click(function () {
 //console.log($(".staffType2").not(this));
 $(".staffType2").not(this).prop("checked", false);
 });
</script>
```

Google key word for differnece between prop and attribute =>
**attr prop jquery difference**